# Groovy XmlSlurper: Find attribute name by attribute value in XML

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper

How can I find an attribute name in XML structure by attribute value using Groovy **XmlSlurper/XmlParser**.
Let's say we have XML:

```
<root>
    <item id="Correction">
        <desc value_err="Error_3"></desc>
    </item>
    <item id_err="Error_2">
        <desc />
    </item>
</root>
```

I need to find attribute name by value (Initial task: find list of nodes where attribute value like 'Error_').
e.g "Error_2" -> **id_err** and "Error_3" -> **value_err**

The only solution I found iteration through all Node attributes map. 
Is there any GPath for it?

Small remark: we're not able to change structure of XML. This is external exception API.

Comment: What have you tried?  What output do you expect? It's hard to tell from the question which bit you're struggling with

Comment: I want to find the list of nodes (`groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult`) where attribute value like 'Error_'. Then it will be processed by Error engine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just do a depth-first search of the XML tree:

```
def xmlString = '''<root>
    <item id="Correction">
        <desc value_err="Error_3"></desc>
    </item>
    <item id_err="Error_2">
        <desc />
    </item>
</root>'''

import groovy.xml.*

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString)

def nodes = xml.'**'.findAll { node ->
    node.attributes().find { it.value.startsWith 'Error_' }
}
```